# Call JavaScript function from within a <td> in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table, somewhat like this.

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                     @item.FullName
                </td>
                <td>
                    //Call the JavaScript function here - MyFunction(@item.Id) and form the `<a>` tag
                </td>


            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

My Javascript function.

```
MyFunction(Parameter1)
{
    var aTag = "";
    .....
    .....   //some formatting as per needs

    aTag = '<a id="' + Parameter1 + '" alt="' + someAlt + '" title="' + someTitle + '" style ="color:Blue;text-decoration:underline;" href="#" onclick="fnAnotherFunction(' + P1 + ',' + P2 + ');">' + NameofTheTag + '</a>';

    return aTag;
}
```

The `JavaScript` function is creating an anchor tag which needs to be formed at the `<td>`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you form the link tag in reaction to some user action ?

Comment: You cant. Razor code is server side code - its parsed on the server before its sent to the client. Javascript is client side code. Not clear what you what to do but why cant you just create that `<a>` element on the server?

Comment: @RobertMoskal nope, it is just a dynamic <a> tag with some parameters from the server side.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - you mean to say I can do it from with the `foreach` loop for `td` itself?

Comment: Don't see why not. Just move the put the `<a id="@item.Id" alt=".. >` in the  the second `<td>` tag (but not entirely sure what your trying to do). In any case why would you need to give an `<a>` tag an `id` attribute? And learn to use css rather than inline styles and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting your mark-up with behavior

Comment: the anchor tag is conditional...I can create 4 types of anchor tags based on the parameters sent...can this done there?

Comment: If the parameters are from the server side, then yes of course. Its the only way you can do it (unless you were to assign all those parameters to javascript variables and then run some script in `document.ready` - but that seems unnecessary)

Comment: yes the parameters are from server side....let me quickly give it a try

Comment: Also `alt` is not valid for an `<a>` tag (are you getting mixed up with `<img>`?)

Comment: looks like it is working fine :)